# Laravel 10 - CORS settings aren't working at all

Tags: php, laravel, cors, laravel-10

I'm using Laravel 10 and now try to configure CORS so that example2.com can make ajax calls to example1.com. example1.com is configured as the base URL for the application. I have the following configurations in `config/cors.php`:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [
        'example1.com',
        'example2.com',
    ],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

In App\Kernel, I added the following line to the `$middleware` array:

```
\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class
```

When I try to make an ajax call from example2.com to an endpoint on example1.com, it gives the following message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example1.com/my-endpoint' from origin 'https://example2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: Try adding `https://` to the allowed_origin urls.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache and `https://` didn't work

Comment: If you change `'allowed_origins' => ['example1.com','example2.com',]` to `'allowed_origins' => ['*']` does it work? For debugging purpose

Comment: It doesn't. For some reason these configs doesn't seem to be used...